# What is the 'technical name' for the Windows Run option?

Tags: windows, run-dialog

Tried getting a term for it after a bit but my google-fu doesn't work well for Windows. What do MS people call this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply called the Run Command

MS uses this [terminology too](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-happened-run-command#1TC=windows-7) as does the [MSDN site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/07/win8-howto-12-show-and-use-run-command.aspx) as does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command)